# Firefox extension to copy the title and URL of the page to the clipboard

Tags: firefox, clipboard, url

I'm looking for a Firefox extension that will copy both the URL and Title of the current page to the clipboard.  Ideally, this would happen when you press ctrl-c without anything selected.   Adding a context menu for it would also be acceptable.

I thought I used to have an extension to do this, but I can't find anything like it now.

Comment: [tag:windows], [tag:linux] or [tag:osx]? (not all extensions are available for all operating systems)

Comment: I'm on Linux but the suggestions so far have been cross platform.

Comment: I wish I could remember it, but I used to use a great one which did that and **also** inserted an HTML comment with the URL into a page if you saved it.  Aha!  See https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/saved-from-url/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I've been using [Copy as Markdown](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-as-markdown/) which allows copying the current page title and URL or any link in markdown format which can be pasted into Stack Exchange.

Other plugins that I have used in the past are no longer available:

- Copy Fixer
- Copy Title and Description

Answer (score 8):

My recommendation clearly is **[CoLT](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/colt/)**. How it matches your requirements:

- **Copy on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>:** Sorry, no – that would interfere with pre-defined shortcuts. But as your second option names *Context Menu*: Yes, definitely.
- **Copies title and URL of current page:** Sure. In different formats. Even by formats you define.

So here come the goodies. First, it is operated via the context menu. The first image below shows how it looks like when there is some link selected; if there's not, "Copy Link Text..." simply reads "Copy page title and address". But the sub-items are the same. In the sub menu you see you can copy it in different formats. The latest version comes pre-configured almost as the screenshot shows, just FuseTalk has been replaced by Markdown, so it's fine for Stack Exchange.

[image: Context Menu] [image: Configuration]
<sup>**CoLT:** Context menu / Configuration Screen (source: [CoLT Addon page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/colt/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

The second screenshot shows you the configuration screen. As you can see, it's easy to define your own formats – so you can adjust it easily to whatever you need. A built-in help page gives advice concerning the placeholders used:

[image: Edit Format with built-in help]
<sup>**CoLT:** Customizing (source: [CoLT Addon page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/colt/); click image for larger variant)</sup>

I'm using *CoLT* for several years now, and I'm a big fan of it. The addon never let me down, runs stable and fluent, never caused any trouble – and I'm a frequent user of this addon, so I must know :) I couldn't do without it anymore, it's always one of the first addons I load to a fresh installation / new workplace. I can recommend it heartily.

Comment: Colt is an old style FireFox extension that won't work in the new FF browsers.   I got so frustrated by the lack of functionality available to FF extensions nowadays, I switched to [the Palemoon browser](http://www.palemoon.org/).  It is a fork of FF from back when you could have an add-on bar before the hamburger menu.   All the old extensions still work, including CoLT.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller As you might have noticed, this answer is from 2014. As you might have missed, that's why I wrote [another answer](/a/47701/185) with an addon still working with FF57+. I share your concerns towards FF, and would look at [Waterfox](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/downloads) – which supports both worlds, old and new extensions. For some extensions, I'd then suggest to *not* update them to their WebExt versions due to lack of functionality – e.g. Stylish or Greasemonkey.

Answer (score 5):

### [Easy Copy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-copy/) <sup>([website](https://sites.google.com/site/smokyinkproductions/easy-copy))</sup>

- Allows you to copy the link and title of current tab through context menu or keyboard shortcut

  - You can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, Easy Copy uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> instead.
  - Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an option to configure custom shortcuts, but I could be wrong.
- Easy Copy uses pre-configured templates

  - You can also add various templates in the extension settings, in addition to the ones that come with the extension, even one that prompts you to enter text, which is then set as link text instead of the title (the "Notes Link" template).
  - You can use various variables while making new templates (with "%[variable]%"), an overview of the available variables is here: [How It Works - Smoky Ink](https://sites.google.com/site/smokyinkproductions/easy-copy/how-it-works#Variables).
  - There are some template ideas over [here](https://sites.google.com/site/smokyinkproductions/easy-copy/more-templates), such as a Markdown template, a JIRA/Confluence template, etc.
  - A demonstration of various templates can be seen below.
- You can also copy all open tabs.
  Via a workaround, you could copy your bookmarks in this way. First right-click on your bookmarks folder, then click "Open All in Tabs", and then use Easy Copy to copy all open tabs.
- You can configure if you'd like some things to be omitted from copied link text, such as ": Add-ons for Firefox".

[image: Templates]
Templates

[image: "Title link" and "Markdown link"]
"Title" link and "Markdown" link

[image: "Notes link"]
"Notes link" (you could also make a "Markdown Notes" link)

[image: Formatting options]
Formatting options

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [Copy Urls Expert](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-urls-expert/), a good balance in terms of customization and ease of use.

I needed a Firefox extension that could copy the web address (URL) of each tab into the system clipboard. Copy Urls Expert fits my needs and it matches the OP's requirements as well, so I've decided to add it to the answers.

From the Firefox Add-ons page that I've linked before:

> Copy multiple urls (links) to the clipboard. Provides options to copy urls
>   of all opened tabs and urls in selected text. You can customize the
>   format of copied urls. You can also open multiple links from
>   clipboard.

The source code is available on GitHub: [copy-urls-expert](https://github.com/kashiif/copy-urls-expert/)

Here are a couple of screenshots I took while I was testing it:

[image: Copy Urls Expert in action]

[image: Copy Urls Expert customization]

As shown in the previous image, the output can be easily customized to the format required.

Answer (score 3):

As my [answer with CoLT](/a/3779/185) is only valid for Firefox < v57 (and CoLT won't be maintained anymore), a good replacement is **[Format Link](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/format-link3/):** excellent support by the dev.

Again, no Ctrl-C directly on the page, but a context menu is available. There's also a toolbar button available which lets you edit the captured text, and switch between the formattings. Next to some preconfigured formats, you also can define your own.

[image: toolbar button opened] [image: context menu]
<sup>*Format Link:* toolbar button (opened), context menu entry (click images for larger variants)</sup>

For the context menu you can either have your preferred format as single entry, or a sub menu with all configured formats. Unfortunately, not both at the same time – again a limitation of Mozilla's WebExt API.

A Plus of this addon is: If you mark some text anywhere on the page, and then use the context menu to capture the URL (either of a link on the page when right-clicked on it, or of the entire page when right-clicked in an empty area), the marked text will be taken as description for the link.

Note however that none of the new WebExt stuff can work on Mozilla's own pages. That's not the fault of the AddOn devs, but of Mozilla locking that (in the API and on their site). Remember that compared with the previous API, WebExt is very limited – and many AddOns lost functionality.

Answer (score 2):

**All** of the above recommendations are dead...

I tried this one out just now, and it works excellently: [Copy Selected Tabs to Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/copy-selected-tabs-to-clipboar/)

(P.S.: Yes, I did use it to generate that markdown link. ;)

---

I like that you can create your own formatting scheme, e.g. I created:

`&One Liner` `%TITLE%: %URL%`

which yields:

`Firefox extension to copy the title and URL of the page to the clipboard - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/firefox-extension-to-copy-the-title-and-url-of-the-page-to-the-clipboard`

---

Honorable mentions that I also looked at but didn't try, but they had a good rating:

[Export Tabs URLs – Get this Extension for  Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-tabs-urls-and-titles/)

[Copy All Tab Urls – Get this Extension for  Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-all-tab-urls-we/)

I didn't use these primarily because they don't have a "selected tabs" feature.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to try dozens of Firefox addons that copy/export tabs URLs lately.
Searching on [Mozilla Firefox extensions catalog](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/extensions/), at the moment I write, seems like the most popular addons to do the job are
[Export Tabs URLs](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/export-tabs-urls-and-titles/) and [Copy All Tab Urls](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/copy-all-tab-urls-we/)
but digging a little bit more I think there are better alternatives, so now I'll suggest the ones I prefer.

### The ones if you just need to copy to clipboard

**A)** The first one I would suggest is [Copy URL To Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/url2clipboard/).

After installing it you'll find a new "Copy URL To Clipboard" item in tabs context menu (as well as a "Copy Page URL" item in documents context menu) plus a new tool button that opens a popup when clicked (see image below).
You can also use it via keyboard shortcut (default one is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but you can change that anytime: https://support.mozilla.org/kb/manage-extension-shortcuts-firefox).
This extension will give you options to copy to clipboard URLs and titles of your current tab or your current selection of tabs (if you [select multiple Firefox tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/1270888/firefox-quantum-select-multiple-tabs)) or the ones of all tabs opened on current Firefox window (including pinned ones) with option to exclude the current one. (When I say tabs on current Firefox window I mean only those = if you have more than one Firefox windows opened the tabs opened on the others windows won't be taken into account.)
It provides several formats as HTML, Markdown, LaTeX and many others. Afaik, the author isn't planning to add custom formats but if you'd like other formats to be supported you can send a feature request to [his GitHub's repo](https://github.com/asamuzaK/url2clipboard) (I'd ask for Json by my side).
There's one more unique feature that this addons provide compared to the others I'll suggest here and it's that it lets you do the copy for links on the document as well.
To do that simply right-click on a link element inside the page and you'll notice a "Copy Link URL" item in the context menu (if you select some text before right-click, that selected text will be used for the content of the link).

[image: Highlights on Firefox addons I'm talking about here]

Close seconds/Notable mentions:

1. [CopyTabTitleUrl](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/copytabtitleurl/).
   This one adds a new "CopyTabTitleUrl" command into tab context menu plus a new button as well that opens a popup when clicked. It also provide usage via keyboard shortcut.
   The copy action can be performed on current (multiple) selected tab(s) only or the whole opened tabs on current window or even on all Firefox windows you have opened (pinned tabs always included).
   The addon lets you copy the title and URL (or just one of the two) plus custom format (Markdown is set as default one).
2. [Copy Selected Tabs to Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/copy-selected-tabs-to-clipboar/).
   (@Andrew already suggested this here in his answer)
   The addon's name is quite self-explanatory, after installing it a "Copy Tabs to Clipboard" command will be available into the tab(s) context menu.
   The addon lets you copy to clipboard URLs+titles of all your currently selected tabs (or the single currently selected one if you didn't [select multiple Firefox tabs](https://www.howtogeek.com/407538/how-to-select-and-close-multiple-chrome-or-firefox-tabs-at-once/))
   It can also copy in other formats, HTML link and Markdown are there already, you can customize it adding others (I think this one offers the best custom format capabilities compared to others I listed here).
   Then finally you can also associate Firefox keyboards shortcuts for every format.
   This one would be the most straight-forward as far as you need to copy one or few tabs URLs ('cause, in case you need to copy all opened tabs URLs and you have a lot you are forced to select them all by hand whereas the former addons I suggested can achieve that with a couple mouse clicks).

Ok, now let me suggest a few more addons, just in case...

### THE ONES IF YOU ALSO WANT TO RE-OPEN LATER (OR QUICKLY EXPORT TO TEXT FILE)

First of all, a due premise: this makes sense only if you're dealing with lots of tabs, indeed, the addons I'm going to suggest do not distinguish current selected tab, they always take into account ALL the tabs you have opened in that moment in a Firefox window.

**B)** That said, here comes my favorite: [Save Tab URLs](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/save-tab-urls/).

This addon adds a new "Copy URLs (all tabs)" command into tab context menu and a tool button that makes a popup show up when clicked, the latter being the truly interesting stuff; indeed, once the popup is opened, you'll see a text-area, listing title and URLs of all the currently opened tabs, and commands that will let you filter listed entries, even using regex for it. Besides letting you copy to clipboard the text-area content (btw, you can also edit that if you want), you can as well save/export as a text file or it is possible for you to paste http(s) links in the text area and click on the provided command button to open them up back in new tabs (kinda as when you open all entries in a bookmarked folder). All of this is presented in pretty clean GUI.
Both the tabs context menu and the popup commands always take into account all the tabs opened on the actual Firefox window (so no option for the single tab, as I said in the premise) and also keep in mind, btw, that this will be limited to current window only opened tabs (always including pinned ones) and if you have more than one Firefox windows opened, the tabs in others windows won't be taken into account.
(I wish this one had some little more of improvements, like for example the option to copy only current tab URL/title via context menu, an option to copy only URLs without titles and adding at least Markdown -and maybe Json- format; with those features added this extension would be simply perfect for me!)

[image: Highlight on Save Tab URLs Firefox addon]

P.S.
*Save Tab URLs* seems having a very similar alter ego (a kind of clone tbh) the only difference with it seems it lists tabs URLs only and no titles: [URLs List](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/urls-list/).
And, in case you're looking for an even minimalistic equivalent (just copy or open tab URLs): [tabs2txt](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tabs2txt/)

Notable mentions:

- [Copy/Paste and Save tabs list](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/paste-site-list/)
  It provide more or less the same features of the previous one thus it has a little messy GUI compared to it and it lacks text-area contents filtering and exporting to text file capabilities but kinda provide themes (lets you change color combination choosing between 2 dark ones and a light one) the option to add line-breaks between entries or not and to include or not titles with URLs. It also provide a kind of internal bookmarks system called "Saved lists".
- [Bulk URL Opener](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/bulkurlopener)
  It has a nice GUI with dark/light theme, lets you save URLs lists in a similar fashion of the previous addon I talked about (I think the previous one has a better approach with that imho) but does not include tab titles in any way, just URLs.

Just like in the case of Save Tab URLs, both of them lack to provide other than titles+URLs and support no custom formats, if you need that then go with the one of those I listed above.